# Validated Value still causing TypeError?

Tags: python, loops, validation, input, while-loop

keep running into this error, but I'm confused because in theory I've already validated the variable as an integer before sending it through my function as a parameter. Any ideas? Thank you!

The function is question is: "calculate_distance(n):" and it doesn't like that I'm using the "<>" operators with those values.

```
print("Welcome Astronaut to Apollo 11 - the mission to land on The Moon.")
print("Lets determine the length of your journey so far - It should take about 3 days to reach Lunar orbit.")

# Function Boolean valid_integer(String input_string)
#   Declare Boolean is_valid
#
#   is_valid = is input_string a valid integer?
#   Return is_valid
# End Function

def valid_integer(input_string):
    try:
        val = int(input_string)
        is_valid = True
    except ValueError:
        is_valid = False
    return is_valid

# Function Integer get_number()
#   Declare String input_string
#   Declare Boolean is_valid
#
#   Display "Enter a number: "
#   Input input_string
#   Set is_valid = valid_integer(input_string)
#   While Not is_valid
#       Display "Please enter a whole number: "
#       Input input_string
#       is_valid = valid_integer(input_string)
#   End While
#   input_integer = int(input_string)
#   Return input_integer
# End Function

def get_number():
    input_string = input("Enter your hours of spaceflight: ")
    is_valid = valid_integer(input_string)
    while not is_valid:
        input_string = input("Please enter a whole number: ")
        is_valid = valid_integer(input_string)
    input_integer = int(input_string)
    return input_string


def output_distance(counter, distance, percent):
    print("Since hour", counter, "you have traveled", distance, "miles,", percent, "of the way there")

def calculate_distance(n):
    counter = 0
    distance = 0
    percent = 0

    if(n < 1):
        print("You're still on the launchpad")
        return
    if(n > 72):
        print("You made it! The Eagle has landed")
        return
    while counter < n:
        counter = counter + 1
        distance = counter * 3333
        percent = ((counter * 3333) / 240000) * 100
        output_distance(counter, distance, percent)


# Module main()
#   Set n = get_number()
#   Call calculate(n)
# End Module

def main():
    n = get_number()
    calculate_distance(n)

main()
```

Comment: `input_integer = int(input_string)` ... `return input_string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're validating the number as an integer within the valid_integer() function, you could pass the number as an integer to the calculate_distance() function.

```
calculate_distance(int(n))
```

Or at any other point along the way, for that matter. Return it in the get_number() function, for instance:

```
return(int(input_string))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use int(input) for input number